# I get a Flutter run-time error when rendering an image

Tags: image, flutter

When rendering an image, I get the run-time errors below. The odd thing is that the image displays just fine on the device and it displays on other pages without this error.  The error messages provide no useful information.

Here is a snippet of code followed by the dump:

```
Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                        child: Center(child: Image.network(url)),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12.0)),
                    //Text(image.name),
                  ],
                )),
```

> I/flutter ( 6080): #17     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #18     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #19     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #20     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #21     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)I/flutter ( 6080): #22     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #23     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #25     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #26     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #27     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #28     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #29     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #30     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #31     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #32     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #33     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #34     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #35     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #36     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #37     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:11)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #38     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #39     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #40     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #41     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #42     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #43     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #44     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #45     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #46     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #47     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #48     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #49     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #50     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:11)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #51     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #52     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #53     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #54     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #55     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #56     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #57     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #58     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #59     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #60     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #61     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #62     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #63     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #64     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #65     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #66     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #67     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #68     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #69     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:11)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #70     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #71     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #72     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #73     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #74     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #75     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #76     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #77     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #78     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #79     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #80     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #81     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #82     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #83     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #84     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #85     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #86     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #87     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #88     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #89     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #90     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #91     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:11)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #92     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #93     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #94     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #95     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #96     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #97     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #98     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:11)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #99     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #100    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #101    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4982:32)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #102    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #103    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #104    _TheatreElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:494:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #105    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #106    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #107    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #108    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #109    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #110    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:11)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #111    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #112    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #113    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #114    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #115    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #116    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #117    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #118    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #119    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #120    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #121    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #122    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #123    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #124    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #125    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #126    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:11)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #127    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #128    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #129    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #219    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #220    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #221    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #222    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #223    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #224    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #225    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:11)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #226    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #227    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #228    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #229    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #230    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #231    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #232    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #233    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #234    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #235    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #236    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #237    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #238    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:11)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #239    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #240    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #241    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #242    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #243    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #244    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #245    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #246    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #247    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #248    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #249    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #250    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #251    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:11)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #252    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #253    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #254    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #255    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #256    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #257    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #258    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #259    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #260    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #261    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #262    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #263    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #264    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #265    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #266    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #267    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #268    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #269    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #270    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #271    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #272    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #273    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #274    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #275    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #276    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #277    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #278    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #327    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #328    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #329    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #330    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #331    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #332    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #333    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #334    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #335    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #336    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #337    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #338    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #339    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:11)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #340    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #341    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #342    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #343    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #344    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #345    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #346    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:11)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #347    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #348    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)I/flutter ( 6080): #349    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #350    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4659:32)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #351    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4992:17)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #352    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2748:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #353    _TheatreElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:508:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #354    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2748:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #355    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #356    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #357    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3894:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #358    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2748:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #359    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #360    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #361    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4006:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #362    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2748:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #363    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #364    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2748:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #365    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #366    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #367    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3894:5)I/flutter ( 6080): #368    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2748:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #369    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #370    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2748:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #371    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #372    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2748:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #373    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #374    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #375    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2273:33)I/flutter ( 6080): #376    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:700:20)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #377    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:268:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #378    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:988:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #379    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:928:9)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #380    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:840:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #384    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:209:10)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): #385    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:168:3)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): (elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and package dart:async)
>   I/flutter ( 6080): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter ( 6080): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart':
>   Failed assertion: line 455 pos 14: 'url != null': is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `url` is sometimes `null`? How is the `url` passed into your widget, did you make sure it is never null?

To workaround the symptom you could simply catch the error

```dart
  child: Center(child: url == null ? Container() : Image.network(url)),
```

but preferable, make sure the `url` is never null to begin with.

Comment: Thank you! Your coding suggestion eliminated the run-time error and the image displays successfully.  Still don't understand why, but, hey, as long as it works!

Comment: what's not to understand? the `url` argument is null. Can you post a bit more context, where you get `url` from? maybe I can shed some light.. 
and if it solved your problem, it would be nice if you could accept or upvote the answer, thanks.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the image displays even though the url is null.  Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow and will accept the answer.

Comment: because the `url` is initially null and later set. So wherever you are setting your url, it is too late and the widget was already built.